# Why does executing a git command in a git hook stop the rest of the hook script from finishing?

Tags: git, bash, shell, sh

I put the line `exec git --git-dir /home/gcom370p/stu013/express/.git pull /home/gcom370p/stu013/express.git master` in the middle of my hook script, and that line executes just fine, but anything after it doesn't execute any more.

This is my post-receive hook script:
http://pastie.org/3574320

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` replaces the currently executing process with whatever it runs. You don't want that. Just put the command without `exec` in front of it. It'll still run the command, it just won't replace the shell itself.

```
git --git-dir /home/gcom370p/stu013/express/.git pull /home/gcom370p/stu013/express.git master
```